# Is Any Finite Graph Structure G(V,E) Homeomorphic to Any Example of Compact Metrizable Space?

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, compactness, dimension-theory-analysis

> **The Imbedding Theorem**  : Every compact metrizable space $X$ of topological dimension $m$ can be imbedded in $\Bbb R^{2m+1}$

Following above thoerem, I could roughly guess for given a finite graph $G(V,E)$ if G is compact metrizable space, I could guess the $2m+1$ which is sufficient to embed the graph itself.

Is $G$ Compact? Is $G$ metrizable? Either one of two questions are not obvious to anwer to me.

If so, how could one find topological dimension $m$ of $G$?

Comment: $m=1$, $2m+1=3$

Comment: It looks like your answer implies "Finite Graph is compact metrizable space"

Comment: I didn't know that embedding theorem required compactness, I thought it was true for separable metric spaces.